# Copy specific image from webpage and paste into Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, barcode

I'm trying to take a character string from a cell, copy it into a free QR code generator (ex| http://goqr.me/ ), and bring the resulting image back into my spreadsheet. (I like this generator because you don't need to click "submit" - it updates the image as the text is entered. Assuming/hoping that feature makes this easier)

I'm trying to avoid the installation of new barcode fonts and the purchasing of barcode specific packages.

Using the below code, I can get the browser to open and enter the desired text. I need a way to get the image back into my spreadsheet now. The code I'm using currently just returns "[object]" (as text) in cell C1.

How can I use VBA to get this image onto my clipboard?

```
    Public ieApp As Object

Sub Barcode()

  Dim ieDoc As Object
  Dim InputBox As Object
  Dim qrBoxImage as Object

  barcodeTerm = Range("B1").Value

    If TypeName(ieApp) = "Object" Or TypeName(ieApp) = "Nothing" Then
        Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ieApp.Navigate ("http://goqr.me/")

    End If

      While ieApp.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
      Wend

      ieApp.Visible = True

      Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

        Set InputBox = ieDoc.getElementsByName("text")
        Set qrBoxImage = ieDoc.getElementByID("qrcode-preview-image")


        InputBox.Item(0).Value = barcodeTerm
        Range("C1").Value = qrBoxImage

      Set ieDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps detailed over here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23860.print-screen-to-an-image-using-access-vba.aspx

Although the example is used in Access, it's still VBA code so it still should work in Excel

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I need to isolate the specific image, which I can identify by getElementByID, not take a screenshot. The other issue is that the window is not launched in full screen - the picture I want probably wouldn't even be included in the screenshot.